# Calculate the length of the curve 's bow.

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the length bow $$r=4\sin^4\left(\frac{x}4\right), \space x∈(0,\pi)$$
I know the formula that $$D= \int^\pi_0 { \sqrt{1+(r^*)^2}} dx$$
The $r^*$ means the derivative of $r$ so $$r^*=4\sin^3\left(\frac{x}4\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}4\right)$$ 
So I have $$D=\int^\pi_0{  \sqrt{1+16\sin^6\left(\frac{x}4\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{x}4\right)}\space dx},$$
but i don't know how to calculate this integral.

Have anyone any idea what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $1+16\sin^6(\frac x4)\cos^2(\frac x4)=\frac{3-\cos x}2$, then you can get the arc length in terms of [an elliptic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My mistake, apparently I was looking at the arc length of $4\sin^{\color{red}2}\left(\frac x4\right)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First case**

Given the *arc of plane curve* $\mathbf{r} : [a,\,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{r}(t) := \left(t, \; f(t)\right),
$$

the *measure* of its support $\gamma$ is equal to:

$$
||\gamma|| = \int_{\gamma} |\mathbf{r}'(t)|\,\text{d}t = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + {f'}^2(t)}\,\text{d}t\,.
$$

In the specific case, we have $[a,\,b] = [0,\,\pi]$ and $f(t) = 4\,\sin^4\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)$, so we get:

$$
||\gamma|| 
= \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{1+16\sin^6\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)}\,\text{d}t \approx 3.42\,,
$$

integral approximable only numerically.

---

**Second case**

Given the *arc of plane curve* $\mathbf{r} : [a,\,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of law:

$$
\mathbf{r}(t) := \rho(t)\left(\cos t, \; \sin t\right),
$$

the *measure* of its support $\gamma$ is equal to:

$$
||\gamma|| = \int_{\gamma} |\mathbf{r}'(t)|\,\text{d}t = \int_a^b \sqrt{\rho^2(t) + {\rho'}^2(t)}\,\text{d}t\,.
$$

In the specific case, we have $[a,\,b] = [0,\,\pi]$ and $\rho(t) = 4\,\sin^4\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)$, so we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
||\gamma|| 
& = \int_0^{\pi} 4\,\sin^3\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)\text{d}t \\
& = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 16\,\sin^3(u)\,\text{d}u \\
& = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 16\left(\cos^2(u)-1\right)\left(-\sin(u)\,\text{d}u\right)  \\
& = \int_1^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} 16\left(v^2-1\right)\text{d}v \\
& = \frac{4}{3}\left(\,8-5\sqrt{2}\,\right),
\end{aligned}
$$

where, in this case, the integral can be calculated analytically.

---

**Note**

Beyond the computational difficulties of the first case with respect to the second, I'm inclined to the second case since the exercise requires the length of a plane curve assigned in *polar form* $\rho = \rho(t)$, with $t \in [a,\,b]$.